# Get commit where merged branch forked from (with intermediate merge)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log, tig

Lets use the latest available git 2.16.2 and tig 2.3.3.

```
cd /tmp && mkdir fit && cd fit

git init
touch m1 && git add m1 && git commit -m "master 1"
touch m2 && git add m2 && git commit -m "master 2"
git checkout -b develop
touch d1 && git add d1 && git commit -m "develop 1"
git checkout master
touch m3 && git add m3 && git commit -m "master 3"
git checkout develop
git merge master --no-edit
touch d2 && git add d2 && git commit -m "develop 2"
touch d3 && git add d3 && git commit -m "develop 3"
git checkout master
git merge develop --no-edit
touch m4 && git add m4 && git commit -m "master 4"

git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

[image: tig]
[image]

It is so easy to retrieve **the last commit** in `develop` branch:

```
git --no-pager show -s --format=%B $(git rev-parse develop)
```

> develop 3

But I couldn't retrieve **the first commit** in `develop` branch. So I couldn't find the commit where branch forked from.

```
git merge-base --fork-point develop
git rev-list develop..master
git rev-list develop master
git rev-list master develop
git rev-list ^develop master
```

Results are useless.

I've found a solution for question [How to get commit where merged branch forked from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560256/how-to-get-commit-where-merged-branch-forked-from)

```
git oldest-ancestor master develop
git oldest-ancestor develop master
```

Results are useless too.

But `tig` and `git log --graph` are still able to see that `develop 1` was the first commit of the `develop` branch and this branch were forked from `master 2` commit in `master`.

Is it possible to retrieve `master 2` with current git console tools?

Comment: "Results are useless." . . . please be specific: what use do you intend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> git --no-pager show -s --format=%B $(git rev-parse develop)
> ```

Even simpler:

```
git --no-pager show -s --format=%B develop
```

or:

```
git --no-pager log --no-walk --format=%B develop
```

(`show -s` and `log --no-walk` are nearly the same thing; the key item here is to drop the unnecessary `git rev-parse`).

> But I couldn't retrieve **the first commit** in `develop` branch

The first commit in that branch is `master 1`, or `27ee6b8` in your image (the hash ID will vary with the time that the commit is made).  This is also the first commit in branch `master`.

The problem here is that branches do not have "starting points".  Branches *are*, in one sense, the structure—the graph fragment—that one reaches by starting at the ending point and working back to the beginning.  This means that some commits are on many branches; typically, the *root* commit, the first commit you make in a repository, is on *every* branch (though in a repository with multiple roots, some roots may not be on some branches).

A branch *name* is, in general—there are some exceptions—synonymous with the tip commit on that branch, which is why you don't need an explicit `git rev-parse`.  The key feature of a branch name, however, is that it *moves* over time, so that it always names the tip commit of the branch.

See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

If you wish to mark some particular commit, in order to remember it later, the usual tool for this is a Git tag.  A tag is very much like a branch name, in that it identifies one specific commit.  Unlike a branch name, however, a tag is never supposed to move, and Git won't move it automatically.

> ```
> git reflog expire --expire=now --all
> ```

Reflogs exist specifically to be able to observe the movement (over time) of references.  The reflog for a branch name like `develop` retains, for 30 or 90 days by default,<sup>1</sup> the hash IDs that `develop` *used to* identify.  By expiring them, you've removed your ability to go back in time and look at `develop@1`, `develop@2`, and so on.  If you had retained them, you could look for the oldest `develop` that exists.  That *might* be when it was born, and you can often tell:

```
05d0c47 master@{37}: clone: from ...
```

(indicating that `master` was born at this point).

Unfortunately, reflogs *do* expire, so this is not completely reliable.  The tag is reliable, but may be annoying since `git log` will decorate commits with their tags.  If there's a *procedure* for finding the interesting commit, you can use that.  In this case, there *is* such a procedure: you want the commit(s) that was or were the *merge base(s)* of the merge.

To find the merge base, find the merge itself, then find its parents:

```
m=11c63bc  # this is the merge
p1=$(git rev-parse ${m}^1)
p2=$(git rev-parse ${m}^2)
```

Now `$p1` and `$p2` are the two parents of this merge.  (A merge can have more than two parents, but most merges have only two.)  The common point where these two branches were last merged is the merge base of the two parents:

```
git merge-base --all $p1 $p2
```

Since there is only one merge base, this prints just the one commit hash.  If there were several, it would print all of them because we used `--all`.   Leaving out `--all`, we would get one chosen at (apparently) random (the actual one chosen depends on the algorithm used to find the merge bases).

As before, one does not need a lot of temporary variables—we could do:

```
mbases=$(git merge-base --all ${m}^1 ${m}^2)
```

since `git merge-base` takes the same commit-specifier syntax as `git rev-parse`: the `^1` and `^2` suffixes work the same there (and indeed work the same in most Git commands).

---

<sup>1</sup>The expiration times are configurable.  The shorter time, 30 days by default, is for hash IDs that are not reachable from the current value of the reference; the longer 90-day default is for hash IDs that are reachable from the current value of the reference.

Comment: So intermediate merge of master **into** develop will anonymize my branches and I couldn't traverse `develop` commits because only reflog knows how to split `develop` and `master` commits before this merge.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Note that merges *do* have strict parent ordering: the first parent of the merge is the commit that was `HEAD` when the merge was made. The real problem is fast-forward operations, which are not merges but do update branch name commit hash values, and any `git reset` command, which makes any arbitrary (user-specified) change to a branch name hash value.